# Incorrect Module being imported

Tags: python

I accidentally created a file in my directory called `csv.py`

It keeps pulling in the `csv.py` whenever I try to `import` the **native csv** module to open and write to `CSV`.

How do I restore it so that I can use the **native CSV module**?

I'm running Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Maybe just give your csv.py another name (and remove the csv.pyc file if present)?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need it anymore, you can just remove it together with the `.pyc` file or rename it to a more appropriate name.

Answer (score 0):

delete `csv.pyc`if it exists
delete or rename `csv.py`